# Woocommerce show how old a product is in years, months and days

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a code on my site showcasing the amount of time a product has been published for in years, months and days. However, the date being returned is out by a few days causing issues. I assume this is due to leap years and different amount of days in a month.

I have listed my current code below any help to resolve this would be appreciated:

```
//Duration a product has been live for
function get_product_published_time( $product ) {
    $datetime = $product->get_date_created();;
    $timezone = $datetime->getTimezone();
    $now_time = new WC_DateTime();

    $now_time->setTimezone($timezone);

    $dateDifference = abs(strtotime($now_time)- strtotime($datetime));

    $data = timestamp_to_array( $dateDifference );

    return sprintf( '<div class="Joined-time">' . __('Length of Service: %s, %s and %s', 
'woocommerce') . '</small></div>',
        $data['y'] . ' ' . _n( 'year', 'years', $data['y'], 'woocommerce' ) ,
        $data['m'] . ' ' . _n( 'month', 'months', $data['m'], 'woocommerce' ) ,
        $data['d'] . ' ' . _n( 'day', 'days', $data['d'], 'woocommerce' ) ,

    );
}

function timestamp_to_array( $dateDifference ) {
    $y = floor($dateDifference / (365*60*60*24));

    $m = floor(($dateDifference - $y * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24));
    $_m = ($m >12 ? '0' : '').$m;

    $d = floor(($dateDifference - $y * 365*60*60*24 - $m*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24));

    return array('y' => $y, 'm' => $_m, 'd' => $d);
}
// On woocommerce loop (shop, archives…)
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item','dislay_product_loop_published_time', 20 );
function dislay_product_loop_published_time() {
    global $product;

    echo get_product_published_time( $product );
}
// On single product pages
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'dislay_single_product_published_time', 25 );
function dislay_single_product_published_time() {
    global $product;

    echo get_product_published_time( $product );
}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you test the following function ?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'dislay_single_product_published_time', 25 );
function dislay_single_product_published_time() {
    global $product;
    $published = new DateTime(get_the_date('d-m-Y'));
    $today = new DateTime(current_time('d-m-Y'));
    
    $interval = $published->diff($today);
    echo __('Product Launch Date:','textdomain').' '.$interval->y.' '.__('years','textdomain').' '.$interval->m.' '.__('months','textdomain').' '.$interval->d.' '.__('days','textdomain');

}
```

Comment: I have tested this action and it is worked better than before however the days isn't working correctly for some of the products. 

For example, I have a publish date on the 4th May 2006 and it returns 15 years, 5 months and 25 days

Also, I need the return on a new line underneath stating Product Launch Date:

Comment: I have updated my answer now its returning 15 years, 5 months, 18 days if published date is   4th May 2006 . You can echo it as you want :)

Comment: Thank you for this I will test the code out Monday when I am back in the office and let you know 

Comment: Is this answer solved your problem ? If so please upvote :)

Comment: I have just tested the code and it works perfectly thank you :)